# Using query expressions for Unicode strings with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, nlp

I am working with LINQ and and I have a database with columns for storing local content(non-english characters). Now I want to make a query using linq as follows

```
var desc = from p in db.GetDesc                            
           where  p.Category.Contains("xxxx".ToString())
           orderby p.Date descending
           select p;
```

Here the Category column contains unicode strings and the above query string doesn't work. How can I use natural language queries with LINQ?

Comment: could you show me some example of your *p.Category* text?

Comment: GetDesc contains two columns (CatId-int, Category-nvarchar).So, the p.Category contains values such as Sport,** ስፖርት**.( Both English and  Ethiopian characters). So, when I pass Sport in my linq query's WHERE expression, it returns valid results but when I pass ** ስፖርት** in the WHERE clauase, it returns nothing.

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using (LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, …)? How does the generated SQL look like?

Answer (score 2):

Unicode in general should work fine with Linq to SQL and Linq to Entities against SQL Server (which I assume you're using).  In fact your query should be

```
var desc = from p in db.GetDesc                            
           where  p.Category.Contains("xxxx")
           orderby p.Date descending
           select p;
```

There's no need to use .ToString(), since "xxxx" is already a Unicode string.

The problem seems to be with SQL Server.  I tried your query against a table containing your Ethiopian characters, and as you say it doesn't work.  If I query for .Contains("ስፖርት") then **all** rows are returned.

Running the SQL directly has the same result.

Trying a simple query like this fails (returns all rows)

```
select * from TestTable where Title like N'%' + NCHAR(0x1275) + N'%'
```

Here 0x1275 is the Unicode code point of the ት character.

If we look at the [SQL documentation for NCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) we see that only Unicode code points upto 4000 are supported. Unfortunately 0x1275 = 4725 so it looks like SQL Server (even 2012) won't support Ethiopian characters.

Having read that 4000 is the limit, testing reveals that running the above simple query with NCHAR(3129) succeeds (in my case returns no rows), but >= 3130 fails (returns all rows).

Comment: Thank you for your your information. I wasn't aware of the limited SQL 2008 server support for such Ethiopian characters. I used to work with MySql and it was fine to work with such Ethiopian characters there. But I dont know why MS SQL server doesn't support global unicode representations.